# Get daja with Ajax from Method That Returns PageForward

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, servlets

I am working in a SOAP service on spring boot. I need some data on a jsp I am working on but the service of the related end point is not an returning an object or a but PageForward.

Example Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/exampleEndpoind.oim", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    public String ExampleController(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return service.exampleService(request);
    }
```

Example Service :

```
String exampleService(HttpServletRequest request) {
   // some Calculations and Datas
   return PageForward.EXAMPLE_JSP_PAGE.toString();
}
```

As in the example above, I want to show the data that comes after some calculations made within the service, on the jsp page related to the ajax success method. but the related service is not returns object or string but PageForward . How can I get the relevant data from this service using ajax?